# Query for restoring a .bak file to a new Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I am using this query to restore my back up file to a new database.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'D:\abc.bak'

RESTORE DATABASE TestDB2 
FROM disk = 'D:\abc.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'cse' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL \DATA\TestDB2.mdf',
MOVE 'cse_log' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB2_log.ldf'
GO
```

But it is throwing an error:

> Msg 3132, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be   provided.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I am new to SQL Server 2008. Please help.

Comment: Can you take a single backup to a *new* single .BAK file using `WITH INIT`? What does `RESTORE HEADERONLY` show?

Comment: How can we take backup 'WITH INIT'?

Comment: Uh, `BACKUP DATABASE TestDB TO DISK = '...new filename...' WITH INIT;`

Comment: Tried with INIT ,But now it is showing error while restoring : `The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'TestDB2' database.`

Comment: It looks like it is split backup. There should be second backup file. There is restore command for split backup RESTORE DATABASE TestDB2 
FROM  DISK = 'D:\abc.bak',
DISK = 'D:\abc2.bak',

Comment: If there is already a database called `TestDB2` that came from a different set of backups, then you need to also use `WITH REPLACE`. Or of course you could try something really crazy and name this one `TestDB3`.

Answer (score -1):

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestDB2 
FROM DISK = 'D:\abc.bak'
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE 'CSE' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL \DATA\TestDB2.mdf',  
MOVE N'(your DB name)_LOG' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB2_log.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  
REPLACE,  
STATS = 10
GO
```